# Meaning of 黙って買い

Tags: meaning, expressions

What does 黙って買い mean?

No definition show up in my search engine.

Examples in the wild:

> 「増配」は黙って買い！
>   二番底は黙って買え
>   【白抜き逃げ馬】1600万下は黙って買い！ | 逃げ馬を追え！
>   【ユニットストラテジー紹介】男は黙って買い一本！

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First, permit me to talk about the (imperative) verb form:

> 「黙{だま}って買{か}**え**！」

would pretty much mean the same thing as:

> "Just buy it! No questions asked."

The noun form 「黙って買**い**」 refers to such a (great) product or service -- "***an absolute must-buy***".

These expressions are often, if not exclusively, used in gambling and investment.

(For the noun form, 「買い」 is generally pronounced 「がい」 with the voiced consonant.)

Answer (score 4):

I am trying to use this one from your aphorism example 大和証券:二番底は黙って買え.

> チャートで大変重要視される形から格言として使われています。
>   下げてきた株価が最初の安値をつけることを一番底といいます。
>   そのあと反発して再び下げ、最初の安値近辺まで下げる場合、そこが本当の安値になることが多いことから二番底といって買いの急所として教えています。

As in the example sentence from the above, "二番底は黙って買え" is one of the most important patterns in the chart. The stock price going down to the first low price in some period. After that, going up again and coming down again to the second lowest price in some period. That point is very likely to be the real lowest price. The second lowest point is the crux to buy the stock. That's why they use "黙って買え" as an aphorism.

In a more general sense, you might be recommending a friend buy a flight ticket to home. You know the price is already a good price and you are saying "you gotta buy.you can't miss it!" with "黙って買え" if you missed this chance ticket flight would rise from your previous experience.

[image]